# Can I develop DirectX applications using C#

Tags: directx, directx-11

I want to know if I can develop graphics application with DirectX using C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally I'd recommend using [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/) as XNA is lacking a number of features that the newer DirectX versions provide.  SlimDX is a simple wrapper of *unmanaged* DirectX.

Answer (score 2):

[Managed DirectX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_DirectX) is no longer supported - it's been largely superceded by [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA), which mostly targets games but which I dare say could be used for other graphics-heavy apps. The [XNA section of MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb200104.aspx) is probably your best starting point.

Comment: By writing application using XNA, can it be run under PC rather than XBox 360 etc?  Is there a license fee to use XNA?

Comment: @user496949: Yes - XNA is available on the PC, XBox360 and Windows Phone 7. As for licensing etc, I suggest you follow the links and read up on the details.

Comment: What do people use nowadays?

Comment: @johnny: Given how many different platforms you could be talking about, it's hard to answer. I gather a lot of people use Unity though...

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Skeet says Managed DirectX is no longer supported. XNA is a really good alternative however and as far as I can tell it's basically a .Net wrapper for DirectX. I've ported XNA applications to DirectX in the past and the only differences I noticed relating to graphics calls were very simple differences in syntax.